# PSTricks: Only specific color and linewidth for some part of figure

Tags: pst-eucl

Consider the following non-MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,0)(6,3.1)
  \pnodes(0,0){A}(0,3.1){B}(6,0){C}
  \pspolygon(A)(B)(C)
  \pstMediatorAB[
    linewidth = 2\pslinewidth,
    linecolor = red,
    PointName = none,
    PointSymbol = none,
    CodeFig,
    CodeFigColor = red,
    SegmentSymbol = none,
    nodesepA = -1.5
  ]{B}{A}{C'}{MC}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I would like mark nothing but the perpendicular bisector with red and double linewidth; not the line segment nor the right-angle mark.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be possible, so here is a work-around, marking the right angle manually:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-1.5,0)(6,3.1)
  \pnodes(0,0){A}(0,3.1){B}(6,0){C}
  \pspolygon(A)(B)(C)
  \psset{
 linewidth = 2\pslinewidth,
 PointName = none,
 PointSymbol = none,
 SegmentSymbol = none,
 nodesepA = -1.5,
 }
 \pstMediatorAB[linecolor = red]{B}{A}{I}{MC}
 \pstRightAngle[linewidth = 0.6pt]{A}{I}{MC}
 \pstMediatorAB[linecolor = red]{B}{A}{I}{MC}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]